# Determining Line Integrals from a Graph and Vector Field (Image Included)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, parametric

Consider the vector field:

$$F=\left(\frac{2xy-2xy^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}+\frac{8}{13}\right)i+\left(\frac{2y-1}{1+x^2}+2y\right)j$$

Determine $$\int_C F\cdot dr$$ where $C$ is the path $C_1+C_2+C_3$ from $(2,0)$ to $(5,6)$ shown.

I already found out that F is path-independent by the Curl test, but I'm not sure what to do from here? I don't have to parameterize each one of these curves, do I? That seems excessive and there should be a simple way to solve this.

[image: Graph image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{2x(y-y^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}+\frac{8}{13}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{2y-1}{1+x^2}+2y$$
Therefore $$f=\frac{y^2-y}{1+x^2}+\frac{8x}{13}+y^2$$ You can solve for the gradient function by integrating each equation with respect to its appropriate differential, then solve for the arguments which are exclusively of the other variables.
By the fundamental theorem of line integrals, $f(5,6)-f(2,0)=\int_{C} F \cdot dr$.

Comment: So I'm supposed to use the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals? I can understand that, but I'm a little lost on how to find a gradient field from what I'm given. I feel like there's something really simple that I'm missing here.

Comment: Thank you! Completely forgot about finding potential functions.

Comment: Glad to help =)